# RecyclerView itemClickListener in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm writing my first app in Kotlin after 3 years of experience with Android.
Just confused as to how to utilize itemClickListener with a RecyclerView in Kotlin.

I have tried the trait (edit: now interface) approach, very Java-like

```
public class MainActivity : ActionBarActivity() {

  protected override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    // set content view etc go above this line

    class itemClickListener : ItemClickListener {
      override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "TEST: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
    }

    val adapter = DrawerAdapter(itemClickListener())
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
 }

  trait ItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int)
  }
}
```

That seemed very redundant so I tried the inner class approach:

```
inner class ItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
        startActivityFromFragmentForResult<SelectExerciseActivity>(SELECT_EXERCISES)
    }
}
```

And then just setting the adapter's click listener like this:

```
val adapter = WorkoutsAdapter(ItemClickListener())
```

But I'm still not satisfied with this because I think there might be a better, cleaner way. I'm trying to essentially achieve something like this:
[RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick/26196831#26196831)

Any suggestions?

**Ended up going with a variation of the approved answer**

Defined the function in the activity:

```
val itemOnClick: (View, Int, Int) -> Unit = { view, position, type ->
    Log.d(TAG, "test")
}
```

Passed the function itself on to the adapter like this:

```
class ExercisesAdapter(val itemClickListener: (View, Int, Int) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      // other stuff up here
      val vhExercise = ExerciseVH(view) // view holder
      // on to the view holder through the extension function
      vhExercise.onClick(itemClickListener)
    }
}
```

Extension function by Loop in the approved answer below.

```
fun <T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> T.onClick(event: (view: View, position: Int, type: Int) -> Unit): T {
    itemView.setOnClickListener {
        event.invoke(it, getAdapterPosition(), getItemViewType())
    }
    return this
}
```

Comment: how you will call extension function onClick in your activity

Comment: You set the itemClickListener (itemOnClick in this example) in the constructor of the Adapter. The ViewHolder calls it. In hindsight, this still works and I should probably use this more lol. Keep making a manual onClick method every time these days.

Comment: Also you can take Rx or LiveData approaches to avoid using callbacks for passing around your events.

Comment: I'm still struggling to get the onClickListener to work. For the line `val vhExercise = ExerciseVH(view)`, where does `ExerciseVH` come from? I don't see it anywhere in your answer.

Comment: `ExerciseVH` is a ViewHolder subclass.

Comment: you can check this article for the detailed explanation 
https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2023/03/recyclerview-with-itemclicklistener-kotlin.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using an interface

```
class ExercisesAdapter(private val itemClickListener: ItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    interface ItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
        fun onLongClick(position: Int)
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(view:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                if (bindingAdapterPosition >= 0) {
                    itemClickListener.onItemClick(bindingAdapterPosition)
                }
            }

            view.setOnLongClickListener{
                if (bindingAdapterPosition >= 0) { 
                    itemClickListener.onLongClick(bindingAdapterPosition)
                }
                return@setOnLongClickListener true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From your **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ExercisesAdapter.ItemClickListener {

   protected override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

       // set content view etc go above this line
       mAdapter = ExercisesAdapter(this)
   }

   override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "TEST: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onLongClick(position: Int) {
        //do long click here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is BY FAR the simplest, most elegant solution. I don't know WTF Google was thinking when they omitted onClickListener from RecyclerView, but based on the many CLOSED threads on StackOverflow, they REALLY SCREWED THIS UP.

Comment: @Bungles no they didn't. They just didn't expect people to have so much trouble defining an interface that can expose click events to whoever creates the adapter.

Comment: If you read the question, it's from 2015 and I already wrote the interface/trait way in the question. I just thought there'd be a more idiomatic Kotlin way. It's clear that we mostly just ended up not passing functions for RecyclerView. If you check Compose, you pass functions for `onClick`. I just don't know why it's such a highly voted question tbh.

Answer (score 143):

My solution is like a combination of the previous ones with a super clean call from the activity.

**ContactAdapter:**

```
class ContactAdapter @Inject constructor() : RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var onItemClick: ((Contact) -> Unit)? = null
    var contacts: List<Contact> = emptyList()

    ...

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val contact = contacts[position]

        holder.email.text = contact.email
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val email: TextView = itemView.email

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClick?.invoke(contacts[adapterPosition])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ContactActivity:**

```
override fun setupRecyclerAdapter() {
    recyclerView.adapter = contactAdapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    contactAdapter.onItemClick = { contact ->

        // do something with your item
        Log.d("TAG", contact.email)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh nice, I like this one

Comment: Me too it solved an issue when i update UI thanks so much

Comment: Remember to clear the reference onDestroyView as this may leak.

Comment: Thanks, @denwehrle. I love this style in iOS too.

Comment: What is this `override fun setupRecyclerAdapter`? From where does it override?

Comment: I have been looking for a way to replace interfaces with lambdas for a very long time. Thank you very much. If I could give 100000 upvotes, I would have.

Comment: I'm getting the "Unresolved reference: onItemClick" in my fragment. Any idea what I did wrong? Fragment: 
        recyclerListaPotrosnje.adapter = StatistikaAdapter(popisIznosa)
        recyclerListaPotrosnje.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(
                requireContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                false
            )
        StatistikaAdapter.onItemClick = { dataModel -> }

Answer (score 43):

I have a little bit different approach. You can create an extension for your ViewHolder

```
fun <T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> T.listen(event: (position: Int, type: Int) -> Unit): T {
    itemView.setOnClickListener {
        event.invoke(getAdapterPosition(), getItemViewType())
    }
    return this
}
```

Then use it in adapter like this

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    val items: MutableList<String> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder? {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.getContext())
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view).listen { pos, type ->
            val item = items.get(pos)
            //TODO do other stuff here
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder?, position: Int) {

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size()
    }


    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    }
}
```

I am working with my colleagues on [library](https://github.com/Schibsted-Tech-Polska/kotlin-kit) providing such extensions.

Comment: This is called in Adapter. How to use this in mainActivity as callback?

Comment: @bpolat you can create a call back, for example, MyAdapter(private val itemClickedListener: (String) -> Unit), and call it in the listen function with itemClickedListener.invoke(item). In you activity, you instantiate adapter = MyAdapter { /*handle your cb here*/ }

Comment: how to handle longOnClickListener in same way?

Comment: By this approach onClick method not every time is called.

Comment: I notice that if `OnClickListener` is added in method `onCreateViewHolder` then sometimes it doesn't work. So I suggest to add `OnClickListener` in method `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 25):

In case anyone is looking for a more *no-frills* answer, I tried the following - which is very similar to the solution from **AfzalivE**:

In my Adapter class I passed the `clickListener` as a parameter. On `onBindViewHolder`, I've used `setOnClickListener` to call `clickListener` and handle click event.

**MyAdapter.kt**:

```
class MyAdapter constructor(objects: ArrayList<MyObject>, val clickListener: (MyObject) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.Holder>() {

    private var mObjects : ArrayList<MyObject> = ArrayList<MyObject>()

    init {
        mObjects = objects
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder?, position: Int) {
        var item : MyObject = objects[position]

        // Calling the clickListener sent by the constructor
        holder?.containerView?.setOnClickListener { clickListener(item) }
    }

    // More code (ViewHolder definitions and stuff)...

}
```

**Note**: I needed a reference from my list item's container (the root view), which in this case is `containerView`

Then I passed my object as parameter without need for searching it on a list again and handle it directly on my `Activity` class, in the moment I set the adapter:

**MyActivity.kt**:

```
myRecyclerView?.adapter = MyAdapter(mObjects) {
    Log.e("Activity", "Clicked on item ${it.itemName}")
}
```

---

***Update***

If you need to get the position of the clicked item, just define it as parameter on the callback and then send it back later. Notice the `val clickListener: (MyObject, Int) -> Unit` below:

**MyAdapter.kt**

```
class MyAdapter constructor(objects: ArrayList<MyObject>, val clickListener: (MyObject, Int) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.Holder>() {
    // Rest of the code...
```

Then on `onBindViewHolder()` you pass the position when calling the callback method:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder?, position: Int) {
    var item : MyObject = objects[position]

    // Calling the clickListener sent by the constructor
    holder?.containerView?.setOnClickListener { clickListener(item, position) }
}
```

And on **MyActivity.kt**, you'll have to change the way you set the adapter so you can get the position. Like this:

```
myRecyclerView?.adapter = MyAdapter(mObjects) { itemDto: MyObject, position: Int ->
        Log.e("MyActivity", "Clicked on item  ${itemDto.someItemPropertyLikeName} at position $position")
    }
```

Comment: @YLS just edited the post with the update. Check it above :)

Comment: i like this simple and easy to understand

Comment: I liked it! Very concise answer.

Comment: This method should be avoided since the click listener should be set once when holder is created. By doing so you trigger lot of setOnClickListeners

Comment: You can use `ListAdapter` in place of RecyclerView.Adapter and use `getItem(position)` to retrieve current item insteed of passing the whole list of objects.

Answer (score 19):

Sorry for the delay, Got an awesome answer from [this](http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/) link and it was in Java..
Did some Homework and converted it to Kotlin..

Now it is working Properly.. Here is the Code,

Create a class named RecyclerItemClickListenr,

```
class RecyclerItemClickListenr(context: Context, recyclerView: RecyclerView, private val mListener: OnItemClickListener?) : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

private val mGestureDetector: GestureDetector

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int)

    fun onItemLongClick(view: View?, position: Int)
}

init {

    mGestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
            val childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)

            if (childView != null && mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView))
            }
        }
    })
}

override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(view: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)

    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView))
    }

    return false
}

override fun onTouchEvent(view: RecyclerView, motionEvent: MotionEvent) {}

override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}}
```

and access it from Activity/Fragment as

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(RecyclerItemClickListenr(this, recyclerView, object : RecyclerItemClickListenr.OnItemClickListener {

        override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
            //do your work here..
        }
        override fun onItemLongClick(view: View?, position: Int) {
            TODO("do nothing")
        }
    }))
```

Comment: Why do you need a gesture detector and touch event handling when you could just set a click listener on the item view?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ,this way of click listener for Activity based click, rather than in an adapter.

Comment: I don't see the benefit to that considering you can just pass in a `View.OnClickListener` to the adapter from the Activity.

Comment: @Sam Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: This is awesome man, you saved the day for me, and in style too :)

Comment: This is great man...

Comment: If you want to intercept touch and do something else other than click listener where this recycler view occupies entire screen, it will become tedious job. Either you have to write that logic inside or add some other dummy view on top of this.

Comment: view.id not working inside OnClick() and OnLongClick() callbacks

Comment: Even if you were to handle it from the Activity, you still don't need a gesture detector. Just pass in a callback.

Answer (score 11):

**Add ClickListener code on onBindViewHolder fun**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.vieww.textView.setText(arr.get(position))

    holder.vieww.setOnClickListener {(holder.vieww.textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN))} // click event
}
```

Comment: simplest answer but the best one!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: how do I show Toast or use Intent while using this approach? it throws an error

Comment: @RaheelKhan You need to get the context using `holder.itemView.context` and then you can use toast and intent as well. For example: `Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, list[position].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Comment: Are there any downsides to this approach? It seems logical to set the listener where the 'position' is directly available.

Answer (score 8):

Slightly different, based on denwehrle

To use on a fragment, inside OnCreateView

```
 adapter.onItemClick = {it ->
    //do something
 }
```

Add in the adapter class:

```
var onItemClick: ((Contact)->Unit) ?= null
...

inner class contactViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val myItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)

        init{
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClick?.invoke(contact[adapterPosition])
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: @AfzalivE, why?

Comment: @mithril_knight because it leads to leaking the parent class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302341/what-difference-between-static-and-non-static-viewholder-in-recyclerview-adapter

Answer (score 7):

## Updated in 05 - 2019

I think the most elegant solution is to give this responsibility to recyclerView and not to view or even adapt it.

for that we need:

## 1: Create RecyclerItemClickListener file

```
class RecyclerItemClickListener(
        private val mRecycler: RecyclerView,
        private val clickListener: ((position: Int, view: View) -> Unit)? = null,
        private val longClickListener: ((position: Int, view: View) -> Unit)? = null
) : RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener {

    override fun onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View) {
        view.setOnClickListener(null)
        view.setOnLongClickListener(null)
    }

    override fun onChildViewAttachedToWindow(view: View) {
        view.setOnClickListener { v -> setOnChildAttachedToWindow(v) }
    }

    private fun setOnChildAttachedToWindow(v: View?) {
        if (v != null) {
            val position = mRecycler.getChildLayoutPosition(v)
            if (position >= 0) {
                clickListener?.invoke(position, v)
                longClickListener?.invoke(position, v)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## 2: Create/Add extensions for RecyclerView:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import com.app.manager.internal.common.RecyclerItemClickListener
                    
@JvmOverloads
fun RecyclerView.affectOnItemClicks(onClick: ((position: Int, view: View) -> Unit)? = null, onLongClick: ((position: Int, view: View) -> Unit)? = null) {
    this.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(RecyclerItemClickListener(this, onClick, onLongClick))
}
```

## 3: And finally the use (i suppose you use kotlinx)

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.{your_layout_name}.*

class FragmentName : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        recycler.affectOnItemClick { position, view -> /*todo*/ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would someone please elaborate on why this is a good solution?  I’m new to Android development and this seems very verbose and boilerplate to me.

Comment: It's a solution, but your instincts are correct - there's too much boilerplate here. Though it takes a few passes to understand the kotlin syntax, a decent approach can be found here: https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-adapter-kotlin/

Comment: There is no reason to add about 40% of this code.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to write extension function to ViewHolder or something like this.
 Best practice; use **Higher-Order Function**

## MainRecyclerAdapter

```
class MainRecyclerAdapter(val news: JSONArray, private val itemClickListener: (Int) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {}
```

Just add a Higher-order func. like itemClickListener and then go to the ViewHolder class. Write this function to your bind function as parameter and set this to itemView Like that :

### MainRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder

```
 class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        fun bind(newsItem: JSONObject,itemClickListener:(Int)->Unit) {
            //Some Stuff here..

            itemView.setOnClickListener { itemClickListener(adapterPosition) }

        }
    }
```

Use this method onBindViewHolder

### OnBindViewHolder

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.bind(news.getJSONObject(position),itemClickListener)
    }
```

And now you can write your onClick function in any activity or fragments.. Just give as parameter.

### Activity or Fragment

```
val itemOnClick: (Int) -> Unit = { position ->
                newsRecyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                Toast.makeText(this.context,"$position. item clicked.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
 newsRecyclerView.adapter = MainRecyclerAdapter(news,itemClickListener = itemOnClick)
```

Comment: My Savior ! I tried all the others and only this one was working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**3 easy steps:**

**1. pass in argument of your adapter as follow:**

```
class ListAdapter(private val mListener: (ListItemDataClass) -> Unit)
```

**2. in `onBindViewHolder` function, use like this**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val item = getItem(position)

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            item?.let { it1 -> mListener.invoke(it1) }
    }
}
```

**3. and in your activity, use like this**

```
val adapter = ListAdapter {
        Toast.makeText(this, it.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple approach without using an interface, just in your adapter create an init block within viewholder class. Like below

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener{
            //your code here---
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish people would stop answering this question. It doesn't need 24 answers. Especially seeing how old this question is, back when trait was a thing in Kotlin.

Comment: You must never use click listeners inside your Adapter! I repeat NEVER!

Comment: @KishanSolanki why? it was literally intended to be used that way. As in, creating click listeners on the view.

Answer (score 4):

**Adapter constructor declaration**

```
class YourAdapter(private val mListener: (ItemObject) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>()
```

**Adapter::onBindViewHolder**

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    mListener.invoke(item) // <- item instance of ItemObject
}
```

**How to Use**

```
mTypesWasteAdapter = YourAdapter({ it.something()})
```

Basically, you will receive the ItemObject as `it` in the lambda argument.

Answer (score 4):

My simple solution using higher-order function and `let` scoping function to set listener only if `itemAction` has been set

```
// Adapter
private var itemAction: ((Item) -> Unit)? = null

fun setItemAction(action: (Item) -> Unit) {
    this.itemAction = action
}

inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun setItem(item: Item) {

        // ...

        itemAction?.let {
            itemView.setOnClickListener { it(item) }
        }
    }
}
```

and in activity/fragment

```
adapter.setItemAction { // <- it is Item
  // do something with it
}
```

Comment: As like java interface previously used for click listener. I wanted this solution for kotlin, Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, here is a nice working solution:

**MyRecyclerAdapter.kt**

```
class MyRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context, val items : ArrayList<Item>, val clickListener: (Int) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder as MyViewHolder).clickableView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener(position)
        }
    }
}

class MyViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val clickableView = view.clickable_view
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
fun appClickListener(position: Int) {
    // You got the position of ArrayList
}

my_recyclerview.adapter = MyRecyclerAdapter(this, myList, clickListener = {
    appClickListener(it)
})
```

Comment: Unresolved reference: clickable_view

Comment: @ykonda clickable_view must be the id of your view in R.layout.my_item on which you will be adding click-listener.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
public class MainActivity : ActionBarActivity() {
    protected override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        [...]
        val adapter = DrawAdapter(::onItemClick)
        [...]
    }
}

fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
    //Do work
}
```

and SAM convertion just works like in Java 8, so just use a lambda:

```
public class MainActivity : ActionBarActivity() {
    protected override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        [...]
        val adapter = DrawAdapter({view, position -> /*Do work*/ })
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Add full example for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

In RecyclerView you can put click on inflated view inside `ViewHolder` class and call it from `onBindViewHolder` callback method for example:

```
class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val view = view
    val tv_message = view.tv_message
    val tv_address = view.tv_address

    fun bind(listViewItem: ListViewItem) {
        view.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

            Toast.makeText(
                view.context, 
                "Name: " + listViewItem.name + "/n Address: " + listViewItem.address, 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

You can call from adapter `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val listViewItem: ListViewItem = mListViewItems[position]
    holder.tv_message.text = listViewItem.name
    holder.tv_address.text = listViewItem.address
    holder.bind(mListViewItems[position]);
}
```

Comment: Great solution, this one was useful for me. Thanks.

Comment: What is *listViewItem* here belongs to ?

Answer (score 2):

//Step 1 make an interface like

```
interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(position: String)
    fun onLongClick(position: Int)
}
```

Step 2 Inside Adapter class pass one more argument as an interface like

```
class ModelAdapter(var item_list: ArrayList<UploadDocument>,var mItemClickListener:RecyclerViewClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ModelAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ModelAdapter.ViewHolder {
    // create a new view

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.upload_document_row_item, null)

    // create ViewHolder

    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ModelAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.txtRegistrationDoc?.setText(item_list[position].getdocName())
    holder.txtCertificate?.setText(item_list[position].getcertificateName())
    holder.txtFileSize?.setText(item_list[position].getfileSize())
    holder.txtCreatedOn?.setText(item_list[position].getcreatedOn())
    holder.txtModifiedOn?.setText(item_list[position].getModifiedDate())

    //holder.chkSelected.isChecked = item_list[position].isSelected()

    holder.chkSelected.tag = item_list[position].getdocName()


        holder. chkSelected!!.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->

            if(isChecked)
            {
                System.out.println("position>>>"+buttonView.tag.toString())
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(buttonView.tag.toString())
            }

        }

    //(context as UploadDocumentActivity::class.java).onClickCalled("your argument here")

   /* holder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener() {
        override fun onClick(v: View) {

            deleteItemFromList(v, position)


        }
    })*/

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return item_list.size
}


/*// confirmation dialog box to delete an unit
private fun deleteItemFromList(v: View, position: Int) {

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())

    //builder.setTitle("Dlete ");
    builder.setMessage("Delete Item ?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("CONFIRM",
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                item_list.remove(position)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            })
        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id -> })

    builder.show()

}*/


class ViewHolder(
    itemLayoutView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemLayoutView) {

    var item_name: TextView
    var txtRegistrationDoc: TextViewNormal?=null
    var txtCertificate: TextViewNormal?=null
    var txtFileSize: TextViewNormal?=null
    var txtCreatedOn: TextViewNormal?=null
    var txtModifiedOn: TextViewNormal?=null
    var chkSelected: CheckBox


    init {

        item_name = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Name)
        txtRegistrationDoc = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtRegistrationDoc)
        txtCertificate = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtCertificate)
        txtFileSize = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtFileSize)
        txtCreatedOn = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtCreatedOn)
        txtModifiedOn = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtModifiedOn)
        //btn_delete = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_unit)
        chkSelected = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.chk_selected)


    }



}
}
```

//Step 3 Inside your activity/ Frgament

```
recyclerView?.adapter = ModelAdapter(documentList,object : `in`.mobilepedia.com.gicgwaliarincubationcentre.RecyclerViewClickListener
        {
            override fun onItemClick(position: String) {

            System.out.println("Position>>>>>"+position)
        }

        override fun onLongClick(position: Int) {

        }

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin**

Make your adapter constructor like this

```
    class ViewAdapter(
        private val context: Context,
        private val mListener: (DataClass) -> Unit
    ) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<WeekRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

// Your adapter code goes here

}
```

In your **onBindViewHolder**,

```
holder.binding.parentLayout.setOnClickListener {
                mListener.invoke(items[position]) // <- item instance of ItemObject
        }
```

In your **Fragment**, implement like below

```
class YourFragment : Fragment(), (DataClass) -> Unit {
    override fun invoke(p1: DataClass) {

        //You will get the selected item here

    }
```

Comment: how to make two or more Unit ? or how to pass view ? private val listener: ((DataFile, View) -> Unit)?, because i need to know of. the view on adapter , hm

Comment: Type mismatch.
Required:
((ArrFilesItem, View) → Unit)?
Found:
() → Unit

Comment: i got it , attachmentAdapter = AttachmentAdapter(attachmentMutableList) { it: ArrFilesItem, view: View ->

Answer (score 0):

Here is my MainActivity.kt class that uses recyclerview to populate location data. It has a simple on item click listener interface that you can implement.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
        private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
        private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
        private var locationArrayList = arrayListOf<Location>()

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            //create locations
            var ny = Location("New York")
            var la = Location("Los Angeles")
            locationArrayList.addAll(listOf(ny, la))

            viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            viewAdapter = LocationsAdapter(locationArrayList)

            recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView).apply {
                // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
                // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
                setHasFixedSize(true)

                // use a linear layout manager
                layoutManager = viewManager

                // specify an viewAdapter 
                adapter = viewAdapter

            }

    //recycler view click listener implement
            recyclerView.addOnItemClickListener(object: OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClicked(position: Int, view: View) {
                    // Your logic
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, locationArrayList[position].locationName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })

        }

    //on item click interface
        interface OnItemClickListener {
            fun onItemClicked(position: Int, view: View)
        }

        fun RecyclerView.addOnItemClickListener(onClickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
            this.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(object: RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener {
                override fun onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View?) {
                    view?.setOnClickListener(null)
                }

                override fun onChildViewAttachedToWindow(view: View?) {
                    view?.setOnClickListener({
                        val holder = getChildViewHolder(view)
                        onClickListener.onItemClicked(holder.adapterPosition, view)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
//end of interface
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If someone interested in the old way implementation..

I posted full example which also reduces your adapter code as well. It uses the old pattern of getting callback..

**Project level gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"//newly added

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services plugin

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App level Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'//it is used for @Percelize

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'broadpeak.firebase.learning'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

/*kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}*/
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    ////kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"\ // not required above 3.2.0
    ///kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**SubjectListActivity.class**

```
class SubjectListActivity : BaseActivity() {

    var subjects = mutableListOf<SubjectBO>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.question_list_activity)

        recycler_view.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@SubjectListActivity)

        db.collection("tagCollection").get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
            if (querySnapshot.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: LIST EMPTY")
            } else {
                // Convert the whole Query Snapshot to a list
                // of objects directly! No need to fetch each document.
                subjects = querySnapshot.toObjects(SubjectBO::class.java)

                if(subjects.size > 0){
                    recycler_view.adapter = SubjectAdapter(subjects, object : OnRecyclerItemClickListener {
                        override fun onItemClicked(view: View?, position: Int) {
                            var intent = Intent(this@SubjectListActivity,McqActivity::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra("keyTagBO",subjects.get(position))
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

**SubjectAdapter.class**

```
class SubjectAdapter(items: List<SubjectBO>, onRecyclerItemClickListener: OnRecyclerItemClickListener)
    : BaseAdapter<SubjectBO, SubjectViewHolder>(items, onRecyclerItemClickListener) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): SubjectViewHolder {
        return SubjectViewHolder(parent, R.layout.item_subject, onRecyclerItemClickListener)
    }
}
```

**SubjectViewHolder.class**

```
class SubjectViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, itemLayoutId: Int, onRecyclerItemClickListener:
    OnRecyclerItemClickListener) : BaseViewHolder<SubjectBO>(parent, itemLayoutId, onRecyclerItemClickListener) {

    override fun bindData(data: SubjectBO) {
        itemView.tvTitle.setText(data.tagName)
    }
}
```

**BaseAdapter.class**

```
abstract class BaseAdapter<T, U : BaseViewHolder<T>>
(var items: List<T>, var onRecyclerItemClickListener: OnRecyclerItemClickListener)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<U>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: U, pos: Int) {
        holder.bindData(items.get(pos))
    }
}
```

**BaseViewHolder.class**

```
abstract class BaseViewHolder<T : BaseModel>(parent: ViewGroup, @LayoutRes itemLayoutId: Int,
                                             var onRecyclerItemClickListener: OnRecyclerItemClickListener) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(itemLayoutId, parent,
                false)), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        onRecyclerItemClickListener.onItemClicked(v, adapterPosition)
    }

    abstract fun bindData(data: T)

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
}
```

**OnRecyclerItemClickListener.class**

```
interface OnRecyclerItemClickListener{
    fun onItemClicked(view: View?, position: Int)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Two ways you can have an access to recyclerview in kotlin is first you can directly declare OnClickListener in adapter and make redirection inside it and second way is you can redirect your onclick to fragment/activity where you have set adapter of recycler

1.

```
 class CartAdapter(context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_cart, parent, false));
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return 10;
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
           holder.itemView.rtbProductRating.setOnClickListener{

            var iNavigation= Intent(context,MainActivity::class.java)
            iNavigation.flags= Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT
            context.startActivity(iNavigation)

// directly redirect your activity from adapter
           }

        }

        class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    }
```

Second way you can have is redirect your adapter click to fragment/activity and then redirect your activity from there instead of redirecting from adapter

```
 class CartAdapter(context: Context, onClickListener: View.OnClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        var context = context
        var onClickListener = onClickListener
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_cart, parent, false));
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return 10;
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

//set your position to the view
            holder.itemView.rtbProductRating.tag = position

//redirect click to the fragment
            holder.itemView.rtbProductRating.setOnClickListener {
                onClickListener.onClick(holder.itemView.rtbProductRating)

            }
    //        holder.itemView.tv_waybill_count.text = holder.itemView.context.getString(R.string.waybills,5)
        }

        class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    }


Your fragment will look like:

class CartFragment: BaseFragment(),View.OnClickListener {
    override val layout= R.layout.frg_cart

     override fun onClick(v: View?) {
      var position=v?.tag as Int

        if(position==0){
            var iNavigation= Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
            iNavigation.flag=Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT
            startActivity(iNavigation)
        }
    }

  override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        listener()
    }

    private fun listener() {
        cart_rv.adapter=CartAdapter(activity,this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

OH what the heck someone might like this 
We all place edit and trashcan images in out recyclerview and would like something to happen when they are clicked. Here is our Kotlin example

This is in a card view that is inflated in the Adapter

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/editCLICK"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="370dp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivEdit"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/color_Transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        android:tint="@color/color_lightBlue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then in the Adapter we do some binding

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val items = parentList[position]
    holder.item.text = items.dept


    holder.editCLICK.setOnClickListener {
        val i = Intent(context, EnterParentActivity::class.java)
        i.putExtra("FROM", "U")
        i.putExtra("MainActId",items.idD)
        i.putExtra("PFK",items.fkD)
        i.putExtra("ET",items.dept)
        i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context.startActivity(i)
    }
}


inner class ParentViewHolder(view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    var item: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDept) as TextView
    var editCLICK: RelativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.editCLICK) as RelativeLayout
}
```

Simple quick and reliable enjoy

Comment: Great but please don't use relative layout in there

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this solution to open an activity when row is clicked, using a companion object and interface. The activity is opened from main activity since I had to save list state before leaving.

**Adapter**

```
class MyAdapter(
    val dataList: List<objects.ListObject>, val listener: ItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ListViewHolder>()
{

    companion object {
        var mClickListener: ItemClickListener? = null
    }

    interface ItemClickListener
    {
        fun clickRow(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.ListViewHolder, position: Int)
    {
        holder.bindData(
            ...
        )

        mClickListener = listener
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { view ->

            mClickListener?.clickRow(position)
        }
    }

    ... 
}
```

**Main activity**

```
val context = this
private lateinit var mMyAdapter: MyAdapter

fun initList()
{
    mMyAdapter =
        MyAdapter(dataList, object : MyAdapter.ItemClickListener
        {
            override fun clickRow(position: Int)
            {
                openActivityListItems(position)
            }
        }
    )
}

fun openActivityListItems(position : Int)
{
    recyclerViewState = mListView.getLayoutManager()?.onSaveInstanceState()

    val intent = Intent(context, ListItems::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("Parameter1", dataList[position].Parameter1)
    intent.putExtra("Parameter2", dataList[position].Parameter2)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```