# How to add a Onclick listener on a RecyclerView in Android Studio with Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

so I want to have a `onclicklistener` for my `RecyclerView` in Android but I am not sure how I should do that.

I have a `CustomAdapterClass` for my `Workoutlist` that looks like this:

```
class CustomAdapter(val workoutList: ArrayList<workout>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(workoutList[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return workoutList.size
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bindItems(workout: workout) {
        val cardDate = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cardDate)
        val cardDescription  = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cardDescription)
        cardDate.text = workout.date
        cardDescription.text = workout.description
    }
}
}
```

And I push my workouts in like this (in my `Main Activity`):

```
    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.RecyclerView)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)


    val workouts = ArrayList<workout>()

    workouts.add(workout("12.09.2018", "Kniebeugen und Bizeps + Rücken"))
    workouts.add(workout("12.09.2018", "Kniebeugen und Bizeps + Rücken"))
    workouts.add(workout("12.09.2018", "Kniebeugen und Bizeps + Rücken"))
    workouts.add(workout("12.09.2018", "Kniebeugen und Bizeps + Rücken"))
    workouts.add(workout("12.09.2018", "Kniebeugen und Bizeps + Rücken"))
    workouts.add(workout("12.09.2018", "Kniebeugen und Bizeps + Rücken"))
    workouts.add(workout("12.09.2018", "Kniebeugen und Bizeps + Rücken"))
    workouts.add(workout("12.09.2018", "Kniebeugen und Bizeps + Rücken"))

    val adapter = CustomAdapter(workouts)

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

I would like to make my workouts clickable and so I can use the name and the description from the workout to open a new activity with them as the intention.

Any help is appreciated!

I do not get where he put that extension in the "duplicate"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView itemClickListener in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424944/recyclerview-itemclicklistener-in-kotlin)

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Where does he put that extension for the viewholder? The question you linked me to doesnt help me much.

Comment: take a look at other answers as well

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh sadly it does not help me much because I dont really get where they placed their code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Alright guys I found out how to implement a onclicklistener in Kotlin,
here is the link: https://gist.github.com/nesquena/231e356f372f214c4fe6

Answer (score 1):

1. Let's define an interface for this use-case:

   ```
   interface WorkoutClickLisetner{
      fun onWorkoutClicked(workout: workout)
   }
   ```
2. Add `WorkoutClickListener` as member of `CustomAdapter`

   ```
   var listener : WorkoutClickListener? = null
   ```

   register click listener for `itemView`inside your `bindItems` method

   ```
   itemView.listener = object : View.OnClickListener {

     override fun onClick(v: View){
       listener?.onWorkoutClicked(workout)
     }
   }
   ```
3. Do not forget to init your `WorkoutClickListener` where you will delegate action when user clicks the cell:

   ```
   val adapter = CustomAdapter(workouts)

   adapter.listener = object : WorkoutClickListener { 
       override fun onWorkoutClicked(workout: workout){  
      /*your delegation goes here*/`
    }
   }

   recyclerView.adapter = adapter
   ```

Comment: Where does the interface go? and the `var listener : WorkoutClickListener?` is red because it must be initialized. Also in the MainActivity this doesnt seem to be working because of the arrow `adapter.listener = (workout) -> openAnotherActivity(workout);`

Comment: sorry, I assumed you are using Java8 lambdas support :P

I edited the answer

Comment: thats nice of you! but where do I put the interface? does it go in my mainactivity?

Comment: also the `v` is a unresolved reference in my bindItems method

Comment: Interface should be stand-alone, like your activity(in separare file)

i've edited answer, does this snippet was helpful?

Comment: there is a type mismatch here with workout: `val adapter = CustomAdapter(workouts)` and here in binditems the listener is a unresolved reference `itemView.listener = View.OnClickListener { listener?.onWorkoutClicked(workout) } `

Answer (score 0):

use it inside viewHolder

```
  override fun onClick(view: View) {

    }
```

if you have specific id's

```
@OnClick(R.id.id1, R.id.id2)
 fun onClick(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {

            R.id.id1 -> {}
            R.id.id2 -> {}
            else ->{}
       }
}
```