# How do I use Anko Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, kotlin, anko

> *Anko Commons - Intent Usage*

How do I exactly use Intent from Anko Commons inside RecyclerView Adapter/else to new Activity?

Comment: Take a look here to set an ItemClickListener to your RecyclerView : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424944/recyclerview-itemclicklistener-in-kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass adapter postion:

```
class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    init{
        view.setOnClickListener {
            view.context.startActivity<MyActivity>("key" to getAdapterPosition())
        }
    }
}
```

To retrieve in your activity

```
val position = intent!!.extras.getInt("key")
```

**UPD**:
Exact same for any other data:

```
class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    fun bindItem(items: Item) {
        itemView.name.text = items.name
        Glide.with(itemView.context).load(items.image).into(itemView.image)

        view.setOnClickListener {
                view.context.startActivity<MyActivity>("image" to items.image, "name" to items.name)
            }
    }
}
```