# error : "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference"

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I have MainActivity, Adapter, ViewHolder etc.

I am trying to change the value of textView inside activity_main2.xml file from ViewHolder.
I call the function inside MainActivity from ViewHolder  but giving this error.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.soyut.su.epos01, PID: 18042
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
    at com.soyut.su.epos01.MainActivity._$_findCachedViewById(Unknown Source:52)
    at com.soyut.su.epos01.MainActivity.doSomething(MainActivity.kt:180)
    at com.soyut.su.epos01.PartViewHolder$bindItems$1.onClick(MainAdapter.kt:106)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

MainActivity file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



lateinit var mRecyclerView : RecyclerView
private lateinit var sDatabase: DatabaseReference
var trId: Long = 0

var discAmnt : Double = 0.00

var unt = 1

var tr :Trans ?= null

var sb = 0.00
var disc = sb*.1
var tt = sb-disc

var list = ArrayList<Product>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)



    sDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sales")

    sDatabase.child("Sales").addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if(p0.exists()) {
                trId = p0.childrenCount
                println(trId)
            }
        }
    })
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_main)
    mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    mRecyclerView.adapter = MainAdapter(this, list)



    btnGranola.setOnClickListener{

        //add Granola to list
        list.add(Product("Granola", unt, 2.40, unt*2.40))

        var  sbAmnt  = list.sumByDouble {it.pAmount }

         txtSubAmount.text = "%.2f".format(sbAmnt).toDouble().toString()

        txtTotalAmount.text = "%.2f".format(sbAmnt).toDouble().toString()

         // MainAdapter(this, list).notifyDataSetChanged()
        println("list size from Granola :"+list.size)



    }
    btnBrownie.setOnClickListener {
        list.add(Product("Brownie", 1, 2.60,2.60))
        //recView()
        val tot: Double = list.sumByDouble {it.pAmount }
        txtSubAmount.text = "%.2f".format(tot).toDouble().toString()
        txtTotalAmount.text = "%.2f".format(tot).toDouble().toString()

        println("list size from Brownie :"+list.size)
       // doSomething()
    }




    btnTea.setOnClickListener {
        list.add(Product("Tea", 1, 1.30,1.30))
        sb = list.sumByDouble { it.pAmount }
        tr = Trans(sb, sb*.1, sb-disc, list)
        txtSubAmount.text = "%.2f".format(sb).toDouble().toString()
        txtTotalAmount.text = "%.2f".format(sb).toDouble().toString()
        println(tr?.Total)

        // recView()
    }

    btnDiscnt.setOnClickListener {

        //recView()
        var sbAmnt: Double = list.sumByDouble {it.pAmount }
        discAmnt = sbAmnt*.1
        "%.2f".format(discAmnt).toDouble()
        txtDiscntAmnt.text = "%.2f".format(discAmnt).toDouble().toString()
        txtTotalAmount.text = "%.2f".format(sbAmnt-discAmnt).toDouble().toString()
    }

    btnClear.setOnClickListener {
      clearTransaction()

    }



    btnPay.setOnClickListener {
        println("Sub Total : ${txtSubAmount.text}")
        println("Discount : ${txtDiscntAmnt.text}")
        println("Total : ${txtTotalAmount.text}")
    }

    btnSave.setOnClickListener {

        println("xxx" +list.sumByDouble {it.pAmount })
        var sub: Double = list.sumByDouble {it.pAmount }
       if(discAmnt!=0.00){
           discAmnt = sub*.1
           var ttl = sub-discAmnt
           var tr : Trans = Trans(sub, discAmnt, ttl, list)
           sDatabase.push().setValue(tr).addOnCompleteListener {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Transaction saved successfuly !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           }

           } else {
           var ttl = sub - discAmnt
           var tr= Trans(sub, discAmnt, ttl, list)
           sDatabase.push().setValue(tr).addOnCompleteListener {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Transaction saved successfuly !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           }

       }


        clearTransaction()


    }
    btnPay.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, SalesListActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }



}


  private fun clearTransaction() {

   //list.clear()
    txtSubAmount.text = "£ 0.00"
    txtDiscntAmnt.text = "£ 0.00"
    txtTotalAmount.text = "£ 0.00"

}


fun doSomething(d :Double){

    txtSubAmount.text = d.toString()

}
 }
```

Adapter and ViewHolder files.

```
class MainAdapter(val context: Context, val items : List<Product>) :   RecyclerView.Adapter<PartViewHolder>(), InterfaceArray{

override
var list = ArrayList<Product>()
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return super.getItemId(position)
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}
// Inflates the item views
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PartViewHolder {


    // LayoutInflater: takes ID from layout defined in XML.
    // Instantiates the layout XML into corresponding View objects.
    // Use context from main app -> also supplies theme layout values!
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    // Inflate XML. Last parameter: don't immediately attach new view to the parent view       group
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sinlge_row, parent, false)

    return PartViewHolder(view)

}


// Binds each product in the ArrayList to a view
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PartViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.bindItems(items[position])
}

 }


 class PartViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
// Holds the TextView that will add each product to



fun bindItems(prd: Product) {
    val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtOrderNumber) as TextView
    var textViewUnit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemUnit) as TextView
    val textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemPrice) as TextView
    val textViewAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemAmount) as TextView



   var id = adapterPosition

    var unitN: Int = 1
    textViewName.text = prd.pName
    textViewUnit.text = prd.pUnit.toString()
    textViewPrice.text = prd.pPrice.toString()
    var itemPrice = prd.pPrice
    var itemAmount = itemPrice.times(unitN)
    textViewAmount.text = itemAmount.toString()

  itemView.btnPlus.setOnClickListener {

        println("item id : " + id)




        // increase the Product model single unit
        prd.pUnit = unitN++

     // println("Here is the " +MainActivity().list.get(id))

        // bind txtItemUnit from single_row to changed unitN (single unit)
        textViewUnit.text = unitN.toString()

        // change the Product model single pAmount
        prd.pAmount = prd.pPrice.times(unitN)

        // bind txtItemAmount from single_row to Product pAmount
        textViewAmount.text = prd.pAmount.toString()


      MainActivity().doSomething(prd.pAmount)


    }

    itemView.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        if (unitN >= 1) {
            prd.pUnit = unitN--
            println(prd.pUnit)
            textViewUnit.text = unitN.toString()

            textViewAmount.text = prd.pPrice.times(unitN).toString()
        } else
            prd.pUnit = 1
        textViewUnit.text = prd.pUnit.toString()
        textViewAmount.text = prd.pPrice.times(prd.pUnit).toString()
    })


    }




  }
```

single_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtOrderNumber"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp" android:layout_marginStart="28dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.476"/>
<Button
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtOrderNumber"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp" android:layout_marginStart="64dp" android:textSize="8sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtOrderNumber"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtOrderNumber" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.454"/>
<TextView
        android:text="Unit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtItemUnit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnPlus" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnPlus"/>
<Button
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnMinus" android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtItemUnit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtItemUnit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtItemUnit"/>
<TextView
        android:text="Price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtItemPrice"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp" android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnMinus" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnMinus"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.454"/>
<TextView
        android:text="Amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtItemAmount"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtItemPrice"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtItemPrice" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtItemPrice" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"/>
<View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtOrderNumber"
        android:id="@+id/view" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"  android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
```

Why am I getting this error?
or is there any alternative examples to change this textView value from viewHolder?
Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: R.layout.sinlge_row post that xml

Comment: No need. It's this: `MainActivity().doSomething(prd.pAmount)`. You cannot instantiate `Activity` classes yourself, and have them work correctly. Instead, create an `interface` that you can implement in the `Activity`, and through which you can pass whatever data you need to relay. There's a simple example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40584424), but it's in Java. You can probably work it out, though.

Comment: Thanks Mike, How can I change the textValue activity_main2.xml file from ViewHolder? or is there a way to change this value from main_activity function ( outside onCreate())

Comment: Here's a Kotlin-specific post, with some different examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29424944.

Comment: Well, you can't do it directly from the `ViewHolder` like that. You'll have to use one of the options shown in the linked posts.