# Recyclerview Item On Click To Textview

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've Recyclerview Adapter for Activity (UJI2). I want to when I click item in recyclerview, the value of recyclerview will show in textview (Activity UJI2) this is my code

Activity UJI2, this activity have recyclerview and textview (txtuji2) in xml

```
class UJI2 : AppCompatActivity() {

var context: Context? = null
var recyclerViewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>? = null
var recylerViewLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null

private var dbRuleReference: DatabaseReference? = null
private var dbDTReference: DatabaseReference?=null
private lateinit var db: FirebaseDatabase

var tampungkode2:String? = "W2"
var tampungkode3:String? = ""

var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>? = null

var list:List<String>? = null

val listkode2 = ArrayList<String>()
val listkode1 = ArrayList<String>()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_u_j_i2)
    context = applicationContext

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    dbRuleReference = db.getReference("CF_Rule")
    dbDTReference = db.getReference("CF_DayaTarik")
    val queryRule = dbRuleReference!!.orderByChild("kode_wisata").equalTo(tampungkode2)
    val queryRule2 = dbDTReference!!.orderByChild("kode_dayatarik")

    var recylerViewLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager





    queryRule.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (npsnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    queryRule2.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot2: DataSnapshot) {
                            val l: DataModel_Rule = npsnapshot.getValue(DataModel_Rule::class.java) as DataModel_Rule
                            val ll: String? = npsnapshot.child("kode_dayatarik").toString()
                            for (npsnaphot2 in dataSnapshot2.children) {
                                val d: Data_DayaTarik = npsnaphot2.getValue(Data_DayaTarik::class.java) as Data_DayaTarik
                                val dd: String? = npsnaphot2.child("kode_dayatarik").toString()
                                if (ll.equals(dd)) {
                                    val tampungnamadaya: String? = npsnaphot2.child("nama_dayatarik").value.toString()
                                    val tampungkodedaya: String? = npsnapshot.child("kode_dayatarik").value.toString()
                                    if (ll != null) {
                                        listkode2.add(tampungnamadaya.toString())
                                        listkode1.add(tampungkodedaya.toString())
                                        val builder = StringBuilder()
                                        for (i in listkode2) {
                                            builder.append("$i ")
                                        }
                                        Toast.makeText(this@UJI2, builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                    }
                                }
                                recylerViewLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                                recyclerview1!!.layoutManager = recylerViewLayoutManager
                                recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(listkode1, listkode2,this@UJI2)
                                recyclerview1!!.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
                            }
                        }
                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                            // Failed to read value
                            //Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
    })
}

fun set2text(text:String){
    txtuji2.setText(text)
}
```

}

And RecyclerView Adapter, I've also made object of Activity UJI2 as ux

```
    class RecyclerViewAdapter(
    var SubjectValues2: ArrayList<String>,
    var SubjectValues: ArrayList<String>,
    var context: Context
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    var view1: View? = null
    var viewHolder1: ViewHolder? = null
    var textView: TextView? = null
    var ux= UJI2()
    fun RecyclerViewAdapter(SubjectValues2: ArrayList<String>, SubjectValues: ArrayList<String>, context: Context?) {
        this.SubjectValues = SubjectValues
        this.SubjectValues2 = SubjectValues2
        this.context = context!!
        ux = (context as UJI2?)!!
    }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.textView2.text = SubjectValues2[position]
    holder.textView.text = SubjectValues[position]
    holder.textView.setOnClickListener {
        ux.txtuji2.text= SubjectValues2[position]
    }
}

class ViewHolder(v: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v!!) {
    var textView: TextView
    var textView2: TextView
    init {
        textView = v!!.findViewById<View>(com.example.explorebatang.R.id.subject_textview) as TextView
        textView2 = v.findViewById<View>(com.example.explorebatang.R.id.subjectkode_textview) as TextView
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
        com.example.explorebatang.R.layout.recyclerview_items,
        parent,
        false
    )
    viewHolder1 = ViewHolder(view1)
    return viewHolder1!!
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return SubjectValues.size
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the value of recyclerview` ?

Comment: sorry, I was referring to the value of the selected item in Recyclerview

Comment: Is has been already answered here. You can find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48803135/13754420

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: null object reference when I pass string from recyclerview items (onclick) to UJI2 activity @AlexMamo

Comment: At which particular line of code does the error occur?